# How to copy files from sharepoint to data lake storage?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-synapse

I want to copy a lot of excel files from Sharepoint to Data lake.

I know that I can use azure synapse with Web activity and next copy activity, but I was wondering if logic app is better.

I would like something that still runs even when I leave the project. Is it mandatory to have a service account for synapse or logic app ?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`In sharepoint:`**

[image]

**`Design:`**

[image]

Then:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

**`In Stotage Account:`**

[image]